# Getting the private key from p12 file using javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, decode, private-key, pem

I need to get the private key from a p12 file I've been given. I tried using the forge library and wrote the following code.

```
var forge = require('node-forge');
var fs = require('fs');

var p12File = fs.readFileSync("C:/Users/macilamanym/Desktop/certs/mayoorancert.p12");
//var privateKey = p12ToPem(p12File, "qwerty");

var p12Der = forge.util.decode64(p12File);
// get p12 as ASN.1 object
var p12Asn1 = forge.asn1.fromDer(p12Der);
// decrypt p12 using the password 'password'
var p12 = forge.pkcs12.pkcs12FromAsn1(p12Asn1, 'qwerty');

console.log(p12);
```

But its throwing the following error.

```
G:\Projects\Tests\NodeJSTest\node_modules\node-forge\js\util.js:1569
  input = input.replace(/[^A-Za-z0-9\+\/\=]/g, '');
                ^

TypeError: input.replace is not a function
    at Object.util.decode64 (G:\Projects\Tests\NodeJSTest\node_modules\node-forge\js\util.js:1569:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (G:\Projects\Tests\NodeJSTest\index.js:9:25)
    at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:441:10)
    at startup (node.js:139:18)
    at node.js:968:3
```

What have I done wrong here? Is there a better way to get the private key from the p12 file? Please advice.

Also please note that I have only been given the password for the private key. Name of the private key is not known. So should be a solution where I don't need to give the private key name to get it from the p12.

Answer (score 3):

I was able to get p12 from file by using this method:

```
var forge = require('node-forge');
var fs = require('fs');

var keyFile = fs.readFileSync('path/to/your/p12/file.p12');
var keyBase64 = keyFile.toString('base64');


var p12Der = forge.util.decode64(keyBase64);

var p12Asn1 = forge.asn1.fromDer(p12Der);

var p12 = forge.pkcs12.pkcs12FromAsn1(p12Asn1, 'password');

console.log(p12);
```

I'm getting `p12` file via `fs` as string and encode it to `base64`.

I hope it will help.